# Google Map Route Coverage Calculation

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We are into Vehicle Tracking System and are stuck into one development phase. Where we have created a Route for a vehicle to use throughout the journey. But sometimes drivers use different paths instead of defined ones. So we need to calculate the coverage %, how much driver covered from the specified route path.

Below is the FeatureCollection for Defined route:

```
geoJson: {type: "FeatureCollection", features: [{,…}]}
features: [{,…}]
0: {,…}
geometry: {type: "LineString",…}
properties: {Bcolor: "#FF0000", FillColor: "#FF0000", Oemid: "10", strokeColor: "#FF0000", strokeOpacity: "4.0",…}
type: "Feature"
type: "FeatureCollection"
```

And below is covered area coordinates:

```
latLong: [[77.02575, 28.44825], [77.02578166666666, 28.448081666666667],…]
[0 … 99]
0: [77.02575, 28.44825]
1: [77.02578166666666, 28.448081666666667]
2: [77.02589166666667, 28.448046666666666]
3: [77.026025, 28.448031666666665]
4: [77.026075, 28.447993333333333]
5: [77.026125, 28.447908333333334]
6: [77.02616, 28.447871666666668]
```

So need assistance, how to calculate covered percentage from the defined route. Tried to understand Google distance API but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps has APIs to calculate the distance. Use them to calculate between points and add all the distance. Now you have the total distance and the distance that was covered by the driver according to the pre-defined route.
You can calculate the distance by dividing them. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Same i did and worked.. Thanks...